# How can I export to CSV when JSON some records contain different keys

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv

I am using an API to get JSON results, and then convert to CSV.  However, I see in the results that some records have missing keys.  The result is that the CSV has values shifted to the wrong columns

I have run my script and also ran API in Postman, and the JSON output is the same.  I used https://json-csv.com/ to convert the JSON to CSV, and compared it to my output.  https://json-csv.com/ output shows that the data is in the correct columns, leading me to believe that there is some code in the background that detects the missing key/value, and fills it with a null value.

```
import json
import requests
import csv

def get_data():
    group_id = 9039
    api_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    api_url = 'https://api.samsara.com/v1'
    endpoint_url = api_url + '/fleet/drivers'

    my_params = {"access_token": api_token}
    my_data = {"groupId": group_id}
    resp = requests.post(url = endpoint_url, params = my_params, json = my_data)
    array = resp.json()
    text = json.dumps(array)

    return text


def write_file(filename, text):
    dataset = json.loads(text)
    drivers = dataset['drivers']

    csvFile = open(filename,'w')
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

    # write header
    if len(drivers) > 0:
        keys = drivers[0].keys()
        csvwriter.writerow(keys)

    # write data
    for line in drivers:
       csvwriter.writerow(line.values())

    csvFile.close()

text = get_data()
write_file('drivers.csv', text)
```

From the JSON output, here is a partial result.

```
{
    "drivers": [
        {
            "id": 158830,
            "groupId": 9039,
            "vehicleId": 212014918234731,
            "currentVehicleId": 212014918431705,
            "username": "rdoherty",
        },
        {
            "id": 134808,
            "groupId": 9039,
            "vehicleId": null,
            "username": "sbermingham",
        }

    ]
}
```

Note that the second record does not have the "currentVehicleId" key:value.  The result is that when I convert to CSV, if there is a missing value, all other values are shifted to the column to the left of where it should be.

```
id  groupId vehicleId   currentVehicleId    username
158830  9039    2.12015E+14 2.12015E+14 rdoherty
134808  9039    null    sbermingham
```

I want the CSV conversion to ensure that all missing values are replaced with null.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend modifying the dictionary and inserting `drivers[key] = None` or `drivers[key] = ''` for any keys that are missing.

Step 1: get all possible keys

If you already know all possible keys you could have, this is pretty easy. Just store all the keys in a list.
If not, you'll have to loop through each driver and find all the unique keys.

```
# write header
driver_keys = []
for d in drivers:
    for key in d.keys():
        if key not in driver_keys:
            driver_keys.append(key)
csvwriter.writerow(driver_keys)
```

Step 2: Add your empty values to each line as you go. Since we're iterating over the same list every time (and not modifying it), we can guarantee the same order, so the values should match up with the column headings.

```
# write data
for line in drivers:
    for key in driver_keys:
        if key not in line.keys():
            line[key] = None  # or line[key] = '' if you like
    csvwriter.writerow(line.values())

csvFile.close()
```

Comment: Hi Kelly. I updated using your recommendation and added the list of keys in driver_keys[].  However, I get the same problem where values are shifted to the wrong columns.  I'm sure I'm making some very basic mistake.  Any other recommendations?

Comment: Hi Gary. After adding the list of keys, did you make sure to complete step 2 as well? Step 2 is vital, because it adds a "dummy value" in the columns where you don't have a certain key:value pair. If we're writing a .csv line-by-line, we must add in those empty cells in order for the columns to line up correctly.

Comment: Hi Kelly.  Yes I did.   In the write header section, I added all keys to the driver_keys list (driver_keys = ["id","groupId","vehicleId","currentVehicleId","username"].  Then I added the write data code exactly as you provided.